# How do I get desired value if no entry is found in the database

Tags: php, mysqli

I have 2 columns in a table. 'phrase' and 'count'.

```
if($conn->connect_error){
echo 'Connection Faild: '.$conn->connect_error;
}
else{
    $just_str = 'ghsfghffgh';
    $sql="select * from dbtest where phrase like '%$just_str%'";

    $res=$conn->query($sql);

    while($row=$res->fetch_assoc()){
        $jso = $row["count"];
        
        
        }    

    }
exit(json_encode(array("name"=>$jso)));
```

I want it to return "Not found" as JSON response if there is no such entry in the database.

**Note:** `$just_str` variable is user input.

Comment: What if there are multiple rows? You're overwriting the variable each time, so you just get the last one.

Comment: There will be only one and unique phrase in the row. Only one row will be returned.

Comment: Since `$just_str` is user input, and you're doing a pattern match, how can you be sure of that? The user enters a letter like `a` you'll return all phrases that contain that letter.

Comment: And if that's true, why do you use a loop?

Comment: You're also wide open to SQL injection. You should use a prepared statement with parameters.

Comment: If you are only starting to learn PHP then you should learn PDO instead of mysqli. PDO is much easier and more suitable for beginners. Start here https://phpdelusions.net/pdo & https://websitebeaver.com/php-pdo-prepared-statements-to-prevent-sql-injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only get one value, you don't need a loop. So just check whether any row is returned.

```
$row = $res->fetch_assoc();
if ($row) {
    $jso = $row['count'];
} else {
    $jso = 'Not found';
}
```